# Newbie question: How do I connect to Oracle db from linux command line

Tags: command-line-interface, oracle, jdbc

I had experience with mysql before, but know completely nothing about Oracle DB.

Recently, I'm assigned to add a simple feature to an existing system.
Albeit simple, I need to connect to the db and get some knowledge about the existing database. But I simply don't know how to do that.
I have ssh access with su privilege on a debian remote machine that can connect to the database server.

Below is the java code I received that should be db accessing part. I think it might help you understand my problem (I'm a really a newbie):

```
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:port/price";
        Properties info = new Properties();
        info.setProperty("user", "username");
        info.setProperty("password", "password");
```

So, how can I connect to Oracle db from linux command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sqlplus. [SQL*Plus FAQ*](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ), [SQLPlus Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technology/docs/tech/sql_plus/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is not intended to be run from the shell - it looks java.

SQLPlus is the usual client used for interacting with an Oracle DBMS from a terminal session - but IIRC its not bundled in the basic instant client package. There are lots of other tools which you could use. If you want an interactive client runing in a terminal session, you could use sqlplus, or [gqlplus](http://gqlplus.sourceforge.net/) (which has better curses integration). There's also pysql, yasql.

There's lots and lots of GUI clients (and because they run on the XWindow system, running them on a remote display is trivial) including Tora and SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, its java. I provided it here just in case I had misunderstanding on the basics of database. If so, you may point it out as I posted the code.

Comment: I got sqlplus by installing Oracle XE Client 10.